# Is there a function to convert a int list to a list that shows the smallest-to-largest order of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a function that turns a list like
[10,5,2,3,7]
to a list like
[4,2,0,1,3]

Basically a list [0,1,2,3,4...] but arranged in the order that the original list has, smallest to biggest.

I have no idea where to even start on a function like this. I have Python 3.5.2.

Comment: So you want a list with the indexes of smallest to largest elements of the original list? Sounds like an interview question....

Answer (score 0):

This solution would work; however, there is probably a solution that is more space efficient. This solution does allow for repeat elements though.

```
l1 = [10, 5, 2, 3, 7] # Your list
l2 = sorted(l1) # Get the sorted version of our list.

# A dictionary containing each element and a list of the indices where they are found
element_indices = {}

for index, element in  enumerate(l2):
    if element not in element_indices:
        element_indices[element] = [index] # Store the index for each element when it is sorted
    else: # We have seen this element before
        element_indices[element].append(index)

l2 = [element_indices[value].pop() for value in l1] # Change each element to its sorted equivalent index

print(l2) # [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

hiro protagonist's answer was close, but he indexed the wrong list.

```
>>> data = [10,5,2,3,7]
>>> sorted_list = sorted(data)
>>> [sorted_list.index(item) for item in data]
[4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

This wouldn't account for cases where you want to account for multiple occurrences and whatnot, but I'm not sure if that's required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> d = [10, 5, 2, 3, 7]
>>> [sorted(d).index(i) for i in d]
[4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```